# Согласование подлежащего с сказуемым

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: На страницах газеты были помещены два рассказа крестьянского писателя или было помещено (знаю, что числительные 2,3,4 согласуются со сказуемым во множеств.числе, но ведь здесь не активность действия). А,может быть, внимание на действие , а не на количество предметов. Оставить сказуемое во множественном числе или заменить единств.числом? Подскажите, пожалуйста.  Срочно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше использовать ед. число, это связано с неодушевленностью предметов, пассивным действием (страд. причастие) и препозицией сказуемого.

Вообще говоря, существуют два принципа согласования: грамматический (ед.ч) и смысловой (мн.ч.). И существуют различные факторы, влияющие на выбор.

Смысловое решение

Если рассказы были напечатаны в разное время (раздельность действия), то используем мн. число, в противном случае - ед. число. Если важно количество рассказов (именно два), то используем ед. число.

Comment: ???

"...и препозицией подлежащего"???

Comment: Спасибо, сказуемого, конечно.

Answer (score 2):

> Как правильно?

Бросьте монету: выпадет орёл -- напишите "было помещено", выпадет решка -- "были помещены".

===

*Что в лоб, что по лбу.*

Comment: Строгого правила нет, там написано "обычно в ед.ч.".Зависит от смысла.Если дальше речь пойдёт об этих рассказах, необходимо множ. число, это как раз говорит об активности - не действия, но отношения к действию. Если они упомянуты между делом , речь просто о наличии- ед. число. Так что можно и не менять.

Answer (score 2):

На страницах газеты было помещено два рассказа крестьянского писателя. Звучит точно лучше!

Comment: А если бы речь шла не о крестьянском писателе, а о Л.Н. Толстом?

К примеру, здесь:

В сентябрьской книжке «Современника» были помещены два рассказа Л. Н. Толстого: «Ночь весною в Севастополе» (так был назван по указанию цензора рассказ «Севастополь в мае 1855 г.») и «Рубка леса».

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответ, очень пригодился.